Worpress website with a PDF file only loads on wifi but not when using mobile data
My website dukagjinilounge.com loads well when connected to wifi, but when I try to open it on mobile data it's all blank. I tried reducing the pdf file size and contacting the hosting provider, but none is helping
SSL certificate is fine
PDF compressing
Contacted hosting provider
Different phones and browsers
Clearing cache and cookies

Your PDF file is too large, the solution you can refer to is: cut the PDF file into multiple images
After that: you can create custom page template (page-menu.php) in your theme: like image below, detail about custom page template document https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/
The result will also display the same way your pdf file is displayed.

